# Removing one word in a string (or between two white spaces)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I have this:

```
Dr. LeBron Jordan
John Bon Jovi
```

I would like this:

```
Dr. Jordan
John Jovi
```

How do I come about it? I think it's regexp_replace.

Thanks for looking.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which database is this ?

Comment: Gary_W and Hemant Patel both deserve credit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way using regexp_replace as you mentioned, using several forms of a name for testing.  More powerful than nested SUBSTR(), INSTR() but you need to get your head around regular expressions, which will allow you way more pattern matching power for more complex patterns once you learn it:

```
with tbl as (
  select 'Dr. LeBron Jordan' data from dual
  union
  select 'John Bon Jovi' data from dual
  union
  select 'Yogi Bear' data from dual
  union
  select 'Madonna' data from dual 
  union
  select 'Mr. Henry Cabot Henhouse' data from dual  ) 

select regexp_replace(data, '^([^ ]*) .* ([^ ]*)$', '\1 \2') corrected_string from tbl;

CORRECTED_STRING
----------------
Dr. Jordan
John Jovi
Madonna
Mr. Henhouse
Yogi Bear
```

The regex can be read as:

```
^      At the start of the string (anchor the pattern to the start)
(      Start remembered group 1
[^ ]*  Zero or more characters that are not a space
)      End remembered group 1
space  Where followed by a literal space
.      Followed by any character
*      Followed by any number of the previous any character
space  Followed by another literal space
(      Start remembered group 2
[^ ]*  Zero or more characters that are not a space
)      End remembered group 2
$      Where it occurs at the end of the line (anchored to the end)
```

Then the '\1 \2' means return remembered group 1, followed by a space, followed by remembered group 2.

If the pattern cannot be found, the original string is returned.  This can be seen by surrounding the returned groups with square brackets and running again:

```
...
select regexp_replace(data, '^([^ ]*) .* ([^ ]*)$', '[\1] [\2]')
corrected_string from tbl;

CORRECTED_STRING
[Dr.] [Jordan]
[John] [Jovi]
Madonna
[Mr.] [Henhouse]
Yogi Bear
```

Comment: Gary, thanks for the regex filter.  I've used them a little for a while but didn't know you could NOT group all the elements, such as where you don't group the .* placeholder for the optional middle name.  I just learned something new too.

Comment: Glad it helped.  The trick is to describe the string pattern as a regex, and group around the parts you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only two words, it will return that. ("Lebron Jordan" will return "Lebron Jordan")

If it is three words, it will take out the middle word ("Dr. LeBron Jordan" will return "Dr. Jordan")

```
DECLARE @firstSpace int = 0
DECLARE @secondSpace int = 0
DECLARE @string nvarchar(50) = 'Dr. Lebron Jordan'

SELECT @string = LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))

SELECT @firstSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 0)
SELECT @secondSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @string, @firstSpace + 1)

IF @secondSpace = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @string
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 0, @firstSpace) + SUBSTRING(@string, @secondSpace, (LEN(@string) - @secondSpace) + 1)
END
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I did this against SQL Server 2012

Comment: Oracle SQL. (I'm using SQL Developer.)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below single statement in SQL Server:**

```html
declare @fullname varchar(200)
select @fullname='John Bon Jovi'
select substring(@fullname,1,charindex(' ',@fullname,1)) +  substring(@fullname, charindex(' ',@fullname,charindex(' ',@fullname,1)+1)+1, len(@fullname) - charindex(' ',@fullname,charindex(' ',@fullname,1)))
```

**Try below statement in Oracle**

```html
select substr(name,1,INSTR(name,' ', 1, 1)) 
|| substr(name, INSTR(name,' ', 1, 2)+1,length(name) - INSTR(name,' ', 1, 2))from temp
```

I tried same example, please refer fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74986/31

Comment: I got an ORA-00904 error: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier, thanks for attempting

Comment: please try edited version of oracle and refer fidlle link for same example :